# Filter text from huge .csv files, in C

Tags: c, algorithm, search, csv, lookup

I have the raw and unfiltered records in a csv file (more than 1000000 records), and I am suppose to filter out those records from a list of files (each weighing more than 282MB; approx. more than 2000000 records). I tried using strstr in C. This is my code:

```
while (!feof(rawfh)) //loop to read records from raw file
{   
    j=0; //counter


    while( (c = fgetc(rawfh))!='\n' && !feof(rawfh)) //read a line from raw file
     {
        line[j] = c; line[j+1] = '\0'; j++;
     }
     //function to extract the element in the specified column, in the CSV
     extractcol(line, relcolraw, entry);

     printf("\nWorking on : %s", entry);


     found=0;
     //read a set of 4000 bytes; this is the target file
     while( fgets(buffer, 4000, dncfh)!=NULL && !found )
     {
        if( strstr(buffer, entry) !=NULL) //compare it
          found++;
     }
     rewind(dncfh); //put the file pointer back to the start

   // if the record was not found in the target list, write it into another file
     if(!found)
      { 
         fprintf(out, "%s,\n", entry); printf(" *** written to filtered ***"); 
      }
      else 
      {
        found=0; printf(" *** Found ***");
      }
      //I hope this is the right way to null out a string
      entry[0] = '\0'; line[0] ='\0'; 

      //just to display a # on the screen, to let the user know that the program
      //is still alive and running.
      rawreccntr++;
      if(rawreccntr>=10) 
      {
        printf("#"); rawreccntr=0;
      } 
}
```

This program takes approximately 7 to 10 seconds, on an average, to search one entry in the target file (282 MB). So, 10*1000000 = 10000000 seconds :( God knows how much is that going to take if I decide to search in 25 files.

I was thinking of writing a program, and not going to spoon fed solutions (grep, sed etc.). OH, sorry, but I am using Windows 8 (64 bit, 4 GB RAM, AMD processor Radeon 2 core - 1000Mhz). I used DevC++ (gcc) to compile this.

Please enlighten me with your ideas.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if I sound stupid.

---

**Update by [Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341970/ali)**, the key information extracted from a comment:

I have a raw CSV file with details for customer's phone number and address. I have the target file(s) in CSV format; the Do Not Call list. I am suppose to write a program to filter out phone number that are not present in the Do No Call List. The phone numbers (for both files) are in the 2nd column. I, however, don't know of any other method. I searched for Boyer-Moore algorithm, however, could not implement that in C. Any suggestions about how should I go about searching for records?

Comment: Hi Ali, I am trying to read a line, then extract an entry from a specific column from the raw file. Once I get an entry from the raw and unfiltered file, I am trying to look that in the target file, that has more than 2000000. I am putting the file pointer to the start to look for the next record from the raw file.

Comment: @ShineJacob: You are not answering question what you want to do but how you want to do it. We already know you want do it in wrong way but still wandering what you want to do. So again: What you want to do? Don't tell us How. We see it and it's wrong. We need more information of character of those data. Especially what characters, what lengths of entries, is there some structure and so, because the complexity is killing you. We have to reduce it.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil - I have the raw CSV with Customer's Name, Phone number, and address. The other file that I have is a Do Not Call List in CSV format. 
The Raw File looks like this: Thomas Anderson, 8821232313, "A-333, I amlost street."
This is how the target file (DO NOT CALL LIST) looks like : "18","1835057558","0","A","1". The relevant data here is in the 2nd column.
I want to filter out those number (from Raw file), that does not appear in the Do No Call List. Thanks :)

Comment: Here we go. It's pretty easy now. You can build trie (or trie like structure as Judy array) and convert your problem from O(n^2) into O(n) which is HUGE performance improvement.

Comment: If you want to do the minimal amount of work: 1) import inputfile and DNClist into a database 2) `delete from inputfile where (not) exists (select * from DNClist where ...)` write the filtered table back to a CSV-file. about 15 minutes of work.

Comment: @ShineJacob Please clarify your requirements. Your question is tagged C and your write *"I was thinking of writing a program, and not going to spoon fed solutions (grep, sed etc.)."* Is it some sort of exercise for you to learn C? Or you just want the job done and you would be happy with a Perl or a grep+awk solution?

Comment: I want to learn the concept in C. This seems something really complicated, as the files I am trying to read, are huge, and takes time to check even one record. Obviously, the method I am using is wrong. You method seems really good. But, I don't really know how to read the entire file into an array (282MB - .CSV format).

Comment: @ShineJacob: Keep in mind that it is way how this problem is solved in real live. You have to chose right algorithm first, then you verify concept in some high level language and then you implement in more efficient way if you need. Keep in mind that there is underlying C implementation of this higher language. You can of course change algorithm by the way to exploit some features of modern HW and OS concepts as SIMD and MIMD features on modern CPU, CPU cache coherency, memory mapping and so ...

Comment: @ShineJacob: If you want read big file into memory you have many options. One is using `mmap`. It is pretty simple, flexible to use because it like you have all file data in one big chunk but you can't use it on pipes. Then you can read your data in one re-sizable (double size every time you reach the limit) virtual memory using block read. And last but not least, you can read and process data by lines or other meaningful chunks as provided high level language examples shows. Use stdio or write your own, but it's tricky on buffer boundary and easy to make buggy as your implementation shows ;-)

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: I was able to read an entire file into a buffer, using calloc(). Then, I used strstr() to search for a string in the buffer, and it took almost a sec. I wonder how GREP is so fast at what it does. Thanks a lot for all that; because of this program I have in hand, I am learning a lot from you, and other users here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

I would recommend you have a try with the readymade tools in any Unix/Linux system, *grep* and *awk*. You'll probably find they are just as fast and much more easily maintained. I haven't seen your data format, but you say the phone numbers are in the second column, so you can get the phone numbers on their own like this:

```
awk '{print $2}' DontCallFile.csv
```

If your phone numbers are in double quotes, you can remove those like this:

```
awk '{print $2}' DontCallFile.csv | tr -d '"'
```

Then you can use *fgrep* with the `-f` option, to search whether strings listed in one file are present in a second file, like this:

```
fgrep -f file1.csv file2.csv
```

or you can invert the search and search for strings NOT present in another file, by adding the `-v` switch to *fgrep*.

So, your final command would probably end up like this:

```
fgrep -v -f <(awk '{print $2}' DontCallFile.csv | tr -d '"') file2.csv
```

That says... search, in file2.csv for all strings not present (`-v` option) in column 2 of file "DontCallFile.csv". If you want to understand the bit in `<()` it is called *process substitution* and it basically makes a pseudo-file out of the result of running the command inside the brackets. And we need a pseudo-file because `fgrep -f` expects a file.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Why are you using fgetc() anyway. Surely you would use getline() like this:

```
 while(getline(myfile,line ))
 { 
 ...
 }
```

Are you really reading the whole "target" file from the start for every single line in your main file? That will kill you! And why are you doing it in chunks of 4,000 bytes? And what if one of your strings straddles the 4,000 bytes you compare it with - i.e. the first 8 bytes are in one 4k chunk and the last however many bytes are in the nect 4k chunk?

I think you will get better help on here if you take the time to explain properly what you are trying to do - and maybe do it with awk or grep (at least figuratively) so we can see what you are actually trying to achieve. Your decription doesn't mention the "target" file you use in the code, for example.

Comment: Also: even if the number of `source` records is too large to completely read into memory, an optimization would be to read as much as possible and only story the `entry` members. The number of loops over the entire 'search' file set should be minimized.

Comment: I have a raw CSV file with details for customer's phone number and address. I have the target file(s) in CSV format; the Do Not Call list. I am suppose to write a program to filter out phone number that are not present in the Do No Call List. The phone numbers (for both files) are in the 2nd column. I, however, don't know of any other method. I searched for Boyer-Moore algorithm, however, could not implement that in C. Any suggestions about how should I go about searching for records?

Comment: I have edited my answer to give you a one-liner that may get you going in the right direction, or even solve your whole problem, with fgrep and awk.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Nice solution BTW. But I'm not sure if fgrep will handle 2M patterns. But nice O(n+m) solution.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Thanks for the help. I implemented a simple hash table and it improved the search operation by 50%. Thanks a lot. I was wondering how grep is so fast at what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with *awk*, like this:

```
awk -F, '
     FNR==NR {gsub(/"/,"",$2);dcn[$2]++;next}
     {gsub(/ /,"",$2);if(!dcn[$2])print}
' DontCallFile.csv x.csv
```

That says... the field separator is a comma (`-F,`). Now read the first file (DontCallFile.csv) and process according to the part in curly braces after `FNR==NR`. Remove the double quotes from around the phone number in field 2, using `gsub` (global substitution). Then increment the element in the associative array (i.e. hash) as indexed by unquoted field 2 and then move to next record. So basically, after file "DontCallFile.csv" is processed, the array dcn[] will hold a hash of all the numbers not to call (dcn=dontcallnumbers). Then, the code in the second set of curly braces is executed for each line of the second file ("x.csv"). That says... remove all spaces from around the phone number in field 2. Then, if that phone number is not present in the array dcn[] that we built earlier, print the line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea for improvement...

In the code below, what's the point in setting `line[j+1] = '\0'` at **every** iteration?

```
while( (c = fgetc(rawfh))!='\n' && !feof(rawfh))
{
    line[j] = c; line[j+1] = '\0'; j++;
}
```

You might as well do it outside the loop:

```
while( (c = fgetc(rawfh))!='\n' && !feof(rawfh))
    line[j++] = c;
line[j] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't notice that. I have changed it. Any other suggestions about reading the records and filtering out the data?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is the following.

1. Put *all* don't call phone numbers into an array.
2. Sort this array.
3. Use binary search to check if a given phone number is among the sorted
   don't call numbers.

In the code below, I just hard-coded the numbers. In your application, you will have to replace that with the corresponding code.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return (strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b));
}

int binary_search(const char** first, const char** last, const char* val) {
  ptrdiff_t len = last - first;
  while (len > 0) {
    ptrdiff_t half = len >> 1;
    const char** middle = first;
    middle += half;
    if (compare(&*middle, &val)) {
      first = middle;
      ++first;
      len = len - half - 1;
    }
    else
      len = half;
  }
  return first != last && !compare(&val,&*first);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  size_t i;

  /* Read _all_ of your don't call phone numbers into an array. */
  /* For the sake of the example, I just hard-coded it. */
  char* dont_call[] = { "908-444-555", "800-200-400", "987-654-321" };

  /* in your program, change length to the number of dont_call numbers actually read. */
  size_t length = sizeof dont_call / sizeof dont_call[0];

  qsort(dont_call, length, sizeof(char *), compare);

  printf("The don\'t call numbers sorted\n");

  for (i=0; i<length; ++i)
    printf("%lu  %s\n", i, dont_call[i]);

  /* For each phone number, check if it is in the sorted dont_call list. */
  /* Use binary search to check it. */
  char* numbers[] = { "999-000-111", "333-444-555", "987-654-321" };

  size_t n = sizeof numbers / sizeof numbers[0];

  printf("Now checking if we should call a given number\n");

  for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {

    int should_call =  binary_search((const char **)dont_call, (const char **)dont_call+length, numbers[i]);

    char* as_text = should_call ? "no" : "yes";

    printf("Should we call %s? %s\n",numbers[i], as_text);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
    The don't call numbers sorted  
    0  800-200-400  
    1  908-444-555  
    2  987-654-321  
    Now checking if we should call a given number  
    Should we call 999-000-111? yes  
    Should we call 333-444-555? yes  
    Should we call 987-654-321? no
```

The code is definitely not perfect but it is sufficient to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your algorithm is complexity. You approach is `O(n*m)` where `n` is number of customers and `m` is number of do_not_call records (or size of file in your case). You need reduce this complexity. (And Boyer-Moore algorithm would not help there which suggested by [Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341970/ali). It would not improve asymptotic complexity but only constant.) Even binary search as [Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341970/ali) suggest in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21957706/49197) is not best. It would be `O((n+m)*log m)`. We can do better. Nice solutions are using fgrep and awk as suggested by [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) in his answers. (I would chose one using fgrep which should perform better I guess but it is only guess.) I can provide one similar solution in Perl which will provide more robust CSV parsing and should handle your data sizes in easy on decent HW. This type of solutions has complexity `O(n+m)`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Text::CSV_XS;

use constant PHN_COL_DNC => 1;
use constant PHN_COL_CUSTOMERS => 1;

die "Usage: $0 dnc_file [customers]" unless @ARGV>0;
my $dncfile = shift @ARGV;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({eol=>"\n", allow_whitespace=>1, binary=>1});
my %dnc;

open my $dnc, '<', $dncfile;
while(my $row = $csv->getline($dnc)){
    $dnc{$row->[PHN_COL_DNC]} = undef;
}
close $dnc;

while(my $row = $csv->getline(*ARGV)){
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, $row) unless exists $dnc{$row->[PHN_COL_CUSTOMERS]};
}
```

If it would not meet our performance expectation you can go down to C road but I would definitely recommend use some good csv parsing and hashmap libraries. I would try [libcsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/) and [khash.h](http://attractivechaos.awardspace.com/khash.h.html)

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware that my approach is not the fastest possible solution. However, it is not clear to me what the OP wants. The question is tagged C (and not awk or Perl), and he writes *"I was thinking of writing a program, and not going to spoon fed solutions (grep, sed etc.)."* He should clarify what he wants. OK, I have asked him.